# how to combine two UITableview in single UITableview's section?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

I want to set two different UITableview in single UITableview's particular section. Is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do **exactly** what you are asking is not possible. but I think that you did not phrase what you want correctly.

You probably want to show data from 2 different table views in one section. As you probably know each tableView has a Data Source. **All you got to do in order to show data from the 2 tables is to manipulate the Data Source** to return exactly the data you are expecting, i.e. joining the 2 data source content for this section together.

Comment: Thanx for the information... Actually i am showing cricket scoring sheet in it...So when i show the batting inning in one section than i have to also show bowling sheet in same table. so have you any idea about it??

Comment: Do you want the same table cell to show information from both, or 2 different cells in the same section to show information from both?

Comment: Cool, in that case you just need to make the change in the data source so that cellForRowAtIndexPath: will return the values you expect. if my answer fixed your problem please mark it as solved. thanks